# How can I make a span change color when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have 4 Spans, and what I want is when I click the link in a span the color of the span that the link is in changes. I also want it so when another link in a span is clicked that span changes color and the previously clicked span goes back to it's original color. Sorry if it's not explained well.
Below is js I got from a question another user asked. I tried to use it and change it to work for me but after lots of failed attempts, no luck. Thanks for the patience I'm very new to JavaScript, any advice or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sec1").click(function() {
            $("#sec1").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

```css
CSS:
#sec1 { height: 8vh; width:10%; text-align:center; position: fixed; top:9vh; left:0;  background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
 background: #7d7e7d; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */;
   display:inline; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;
     
     }
#sec1.active {
    background:grey;
}

#sec2 { height: 8vh; width:10%; text-align:center;    position: fixed; top:9vh; left:10.25%; background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
 background: #7d7e7d; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */;
       display:inline; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;
     }
#sec2.active{background:grey;}
#sec3 { height: 8vh; width:10%; text-align:center;    position: fixed; top:9vh; left:20.5%; background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
 background: #7d7e7d; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */;
       display:inline; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;
     }
#sec3.active{background:grey;}
#sec4 { height: 8vh; width:10%; text-align:center;    position: fixed; top:9vh; left:30.75%; background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
 background: #7d7e7d; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */;
      display:inline; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;
     }
#sec4.active{background:grey;}
```

```html
html:
<span id="sec1" class="box"><a href="" class="one"><p style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em;"><b>MOVIES</a></p></div>
<span id="sec2" class="box"><a href="" class="two"><p style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em"><b>MUSIC</b></p></a></div>
<span id="sec3" class="box" ><a href="" class="three"><p style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em"><b>RADIO</b></p></a></div>
<span id="sec4" class="box"><a href="" class="four"><p style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em"><b>COMICS</b></p></a></div>
```

Comment: Huh, do you really need all these ids and CSS? Also, closing div tags are typos, i guess, or spans are inside divs, actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the box class selector instead of the IDs, and clean up your HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $boxes = $(".box").click(function() {
    $boxes.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
a {color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-family:arial;}
.box {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: #7d7e7d;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #7d7e7d), color-stop(100%, #0e0e0e));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  ;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.active  {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="sec1" class="box">
  <a href="#" class="one"style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em;">
    MOVIES
  </a>
 </span>

<span id="sec2" class="box">
  <a href="#" class="two" style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em">
    MUSIC
  </a>
</span>

<span id="sec3" class="box" >
  <a href="#" class="three" style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em">
    RADIO
  </a>
</span>

<span id="sec4" class="box">
  <a href="#" class="four" style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em">
    COMICS
  </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the markup you posted.

Here a span tag is opened `<span>`, but it's incorrectly closed as a div `</div>`. It should be closed as a span. `</span>`:

`<span id="sec1" class="box"><a href="" class="one"><p style="margin-top:2.5vh; font-size:1.25em;"><b>MOVIES</a></p></div>`

Also your hrefs need to point to a hash so the page does not redirect.

(change all instances of `href=""` to `href="#"`)

Here's a quick and dirty way to do what you want. It has repeating code which isn't best practice (not DRY), but it does the trick. I simplified the js, css, and html to show the concept.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // click box 1
  $("#sec1").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#sec2").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec3").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec4").removeClass('active');
  });

  // click box 2
  $("#sec2").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#sec1").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec3").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec4").removeClass('active');
  });  

  // click box 3
  $("#sec3").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#sec1").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec2").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec4").removeClass('active');
  });  

  // click box 4
  $("#sec4").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#sec1").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec2").removeClass('active');
    $("#sec3").removeClass('active');
  });  

});
```

css

```
.box {
  text-align:center;
  top:9vh;
  left:0;
  background-color: #7d7e7d;
  display:inline;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<span id="sec1" class="box">
  <a href="#">
    MOVIES
  </a>
</span>

<span id="sec2" class="box">
  <a href="#">
    MUSIC
  </a>
</span>

<span id="sec3" class="box" >
  <a href="#">
    RADIO
  </a>
</span>

<span id="sec4" class="box">
  <a href="#">
    COMICS
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/riranefuri/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I thought I deleted those closing div tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove class off every span, then add it to being clicked one.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("span.box").click(function() {
            $("span.box").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But if you wish to use a-tags to walk through *different* pages, you should add `active` class to appropriate link via your server programming, not `js`.